# passing list<string> as argument to web service returns 500 error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, web-services

I have a simple `web service` which accepts list of strings and display it on page. BUT its not working with List, it is working fine with single string.

I dont know whats wrong, please help

## ASMX

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<string> GetStrings(string[] names)
{
    return names.ToList();

}
```

## JQuery

```
 var jsonData = [{ names: "Brian" }, { names: "Neville" }];
        $.ajax({
            url: "/JsonHelper/sample.asmx/GetStrings",
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('.resultJson').append(JSON.stringify(data.d));
               },
            error: function (data, status) {
                console.log("FAILED:" + status);
            }
        });
    });
```

## ERROR

```
POST http://dev.sample.com/JsonHelper/sample.asmx/GetStrings 500 (Internal Server Error)
XHR finished loading: "http://dev.sample.com/JsonHelper/sample.asmx/GetStrings". jquery.js:8706
FAILED:error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a small change to the JSONData variable and it works..

```
 var jsonData = { names:["Brian", "Neville"]};
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebService1.asmx/GetStrings",
                data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: fnsuccesscallback,
                error: fnerrorcallback
            });

        });

        function fnsuccesscallback(data) {
            alert(data.d);
        }
        function fnerrorcallback(data, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
```

and the InternalServerError you got was because the data you sent couldnot be deserialised to String array

Comment: All three solution works for me... +1 to all and accepting this as answered... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set traditional attribute to true in your AJAX call and change data attribute and see if it works:

```
$.ajax({
url: "/JsonHelper/sample.asmx/GetStrings",
data:"{'names':'" + JSON.stringify(jsonData) + "'}" ,
traditional:true,

});
```

**Edit**:

What you are passing is an array of names objects. An array of string should be something like this:

```
var myCars=new Array("Saab","Volvo","BMW");
```

OR

```
var names = ['Brian','Abc'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tried this on my local machine and it works.

To explain I have added a variable to take all the name strings then stringify it(*but have passed my web method's parameter name too*)...also on the web method you were missing `static` keyword(*Make sure you change the url when copying*) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var array = ["Brian", "Neville"];
            var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ names: array }); ;
            $.ajax({
                url: "Default.aspx/GetStrings",
                data: jsonData,
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.resultJson').append(JSON.stringify(data.d));
                },
                error: function(data, status) {
                    console.log("FAILED:" + status);
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

And the method is :

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static List<string> GetStrings(string[] names)
{
    return names.ToList();

}
```

**PS. FYI You can change your Web Method's parameter to `List<string>` and it would still work!**